# How can I train my chatterbot in Python with `Chatterbot` module

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, chatterbot

I am trying to make a chatbot, using Chatterbot, and then integrating it into my Discord Bot... I have done some research and got to know that I can use the Chatterbot library easily to train my bot... But I want to do it, so that whenever an on_message event is triggered in discord.py, it would learn from that... I have tried to use the example from the GitHub repo, and tried to train it, but it did not work very well... And also, is there a way to save all the responses it learns in a file or something... The code I have tried till now, is -->

```py
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.conversation import Statement

"""
This example shows how to create a chat bot that
will learn responses based on an additional feedback
element from the user.
"""

# Uncomment the following line to enable verbose logging
# import logging
# logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Create a new instance of a ChatBot
bot = ChatBot(
    'Feedback Learning Bot',
    storage_adapter='chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter'
)


def get_feedback():

    text = input()

    if 'yes' in text.lower():
        return True
    elif 'no' in text.lower():
        return False
    else:
        print('Please type either "Yes" or "No"')
        return get_feedback()


print('Type something to begin...')

# The following loop will execute each time the user enters input
while True:
    try:
        input_statement = Statement(text=input())
        response = bot.generate_response(
            input_statement
        )

        print('\n Is "{}" a coherent response to "{}"? \n'.format(
            response[0].text,
            input_statement.text
        ))
        if get_feedback() is False:
            print('please input the correct one')
            correct_response = Statement(text=input())
            bot.learn_response(correct_response, input_statement)
            print('Responses added to bot!')

    # Press ctrl-c or ctrl-d on the keyboard to exit
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError, SystemExit):
        break
```

Thanks in advance <3

Comment: StackOverflow is not a “implement/integrate this for me” type of site, you’re supposed to ask specific programming questions. Take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [what topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Well, I need the way, **how** can I achieve this. I never said I want y'all to code this for me

Comment: **how** can you achieve this is indirectly asking us to code, how else would u expect the answer to be? Try looking at a tutorial or read the docs.

Comment: Ceres, I **have** seen the docs, and also the GitHub repo (that's the place from where I got that code). As I told in a comment to another answer (which got deleted), I have seen the docs and specially the training section of the docs. But the only things present there are corpus and list trainers. I can't use list trainers cz I don't have any ore defined lists, and I didn't like the behavior of the corpus data... I am only asking for some guide, or some logic, as to how can I achieve this. I never asked anyone for spoonfeeding (which I don't prefer tbh)

Answer (score 2):

I am still learning the in's and out's of the library and trying to do something similar, so will share my thoughts.

I want my bot to have multiple possible answers to a statement, so I allow multiple trainings to occur for a statement/response.  The bot in turn when selecting a response to a statement in the future would have a confidence threshold for acceptable responses, then pick at random from those.
I also plan on introducing a reinforcement of sorts, where an identified good statement/ response can be retrained multiple times to increase the chance it would be selected from the random responses to choose from.
I did check the database the library produces for statement/responses, and multiple trainings of the same statement/response does in fact generate multiple entries.
In my model, there is no "bad" response to be removed/overwritten, just better responses to be added to the pool and see what comes from that.

All this is still a work in progress.

Comment: oh cool, @SittingJacks... Well, I asked around on discord and got a way, I think... You can use the `on_message` trigger and then use the `TextChannel.history` generator, to get the last two messages... and then feed those to the `bot.learn_response`. I don't have any other way, but would be glad, if you tell any <3

Comment: **UPDATE** The thing did not work. It is not responding to the user, whenever he types in the AI channel, but when I opened the DB, it was showing that it saved everything...

Comment: If the entries are making it into the chatbot db, then it appears to be some communication hiccup between your libraries, or the discord library and discord api itself.    My setup is for twitch chat, so I have no helpful hints on troubleshooting discord library/api for this.   Good luck!